# Best way to show one-to-many relationship in a grid?

Tags: design-patterns, grid

This is probably the most common issue when it comes to grid/table design; How to display one-to-many relationship such not to repeat the item nested.

Please take a look at two solutions I came up with. I was wondering if there is a better alternative?

[image]

[image]

Comment: What is the users' need for the relation? Are they inspecting a single animal or comparing them?

Answer (score 4):

If you only have one column having multiple values (the Categories in the example), you could use a plain two-dimensional array - a feature table. You basically turn the relation as the other dimension, as sketched below.

However, this might not scale too well, if there are huge number of categories.

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f42Nak.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>

Answer (score 4):

You can use tags to display relationship.

It is most compact and easiest way to display and edit data.

See http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I think the categories can be grouped and assigned to different properties. For example, the property "number of legs" can be 2 or 4. This allows you to present the information this way:

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fSyMqH.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>

There are several advantages:

- a fewer number of entries / columns
- items can be easily compared and grouped, e.g. you could allow the user to sort/group the rows by certain properties
- it is easier to verify if an item is completely specified, e.g. what is the subspecies an eagle belongs to?

You can use drop down boxes to edit the cell entries.