# How to display one to many mapping in a Grid

Tags: design-patterns, grid

I am having some trouble finding the best way to display this sort of mapping.

My current grid looks something like this [image: this]

However there is a 1 To Many mapping between a Username (plus the rest of the details) and School.

There is a 1 to 1 mapping between School and School Groups. School groups would generally either be by district or if a private school, then all affiliated schools.

I have had a look at the following [related question](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/50602/best-way-to-show-one-to-many-relationship-in-a-grid) but due to how the School - School Group mapping works, the suggested answers would not work here.

Comment: 1. Could a User have more than one role, considering they may be associated with multiple schools? or is it always the same role? 2. is there a 'primary' school, or are they all equal in terms of importance?

Comment: 1. A User can only have a single role since it is hierarchical, the roles are only there to provide extra access to the admin panel.There is no internal mapping associated with Roles and Schools or Roles and School Groups

2. All schools are the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Try using grouped sub rows, and perhaps come up with some sort restrictions.

Here's a shot at trying to display multiple mapping. Sort gets tricky with multiple school rows, so you could attempt to alphabetize the schools for certain rows.

If you want to compare elements, some strong filters might be of assistance.

The tradeoffs are less repetition by consolidating the user name and unique columns, but more restrictive sorting for rows with multiple schools.

[image]

NOTE: I noticed actions in each row, and my guess is it deletes the user, so I did not repeat them on the sub rows (the school rows). This may be an incorrect assumption.